# Is there any company trying out ion trap qubits?

Tags: experimental-realization, ion-trap-quantum-computing

Analogous to this question [Is there any company that backs and implements diamond vacancy quantum computers?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5287/462)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IonQ, Honeywell, and Infineon Technologies ([list here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_companies_involved_in_quantum_computing_or_communication)).

From my understanding, IonQ and Honeywell seem to be leading in the trapped ion space